# A sequence of real numbers cannot have exactly three subsequential limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The actual question is as follows

> Prove or disprove : A sequence of real numbers cannot have exactly three subsequential limits.

Do I justify this with the help of an example? And if I wanted to prove ith rigorously, I have no idea where to start and what approach to take.
A **hint** for the approach will be really appreciated!

Comment: What is a simplest example of a sequence with exactly two subsequential limits?

Comment: A single counterexample would be a perfectly rigorous disproof. I would begin by trying to find one. If you fail then begin to look for a proof. That's a typical strategy for this kind of problem. Often the failure to find a counterexample suggests a proof.

Comment: The sequence $(-1)^{n}$ ?

Comment: @Vincent Yes. In particular, what nice property do all of its subsequences have? Can you generalise this idea?

Comment: $1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3, \cdots$

Comment: @legionwhale i don't know what you mean by property... I understand that though the sequence itself is not convergent, the Subsequence are individually convergent, and the Subsequence has all of its elements equal to each other?

Comment: @Vincent Each subsequence is eventually constant, which is why it could be considered to be the simplest example of such a sequence. This gives a good heuristic for trying to find a simple sequence with exactly $n$ subsequential limits.

Comment: What about this sequence $(-1, 0,1,-1, 0,1,\dots) $ ?

Comment: You can just disprove it with an example, and finding an example is relatively easy. For example: $\sin{ \frac{n \pi}{3}}= (\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0, 0, \frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2}, 0...  )$ Here we see that there are 3 subsequential limits! $\frac{- \sqrt{3}}{2},$ $0$ and $ \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all the comments! I will take a try to answer my own question!

### Hint:

Justify the proof with the help of an example. Try and create a set which has exactly 3 subsequential limit points.

---

### Solution:

Let us take a subset $S$ of real number such as,
$$ S =\{sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) : n\in\mathbb{N} \} $$
Then we will get $S = \{1,0,-1,0,1,...\}$

The real sequence $S$ itself is not convergent but,
the subsequence $S_{2n}$ is convergent to 0.
The subsequence $S_{1+4(n-1)}$ is convergent to 1.
And the subsequence $S_{3+4(n-1)}$ is convergent to -1.

Therefore we have a sequence which has exactly 3 subsequential limit, namely 1, -1 and 0.